# PyParsing: how to parse a function call and returning it as string

Tags: python, pyparsing

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899845/parse-function-call-with-pyparsing) I have this code to parse a function call:

```
functionName = Word(alphanums + '_')
functionBody = Forward()
functionBody <<= functionName + (Literal("(") + Optional( delimitedList ( functionBody | Word(alphanums + '_') | "''"),'') + Literal(")"))
```

But, when calling:

```
result = functionBody.parseString('function(param1,param2,param3)')
```

I got this result:

```
['function', '(', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3', ')']
```

Is there any way to get this result instead:

```
['function(param1, param2, param3)']
```

That is to say: parsing the function call is well written, but returning it as string instead of as an array without using the Python `join` sentence?

Comment: "...without using the Python join sentence?" and why is that? I believe that is the best way.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar, I am using this code snippet within another expression, and pyparsing returns me nothing but errors if I don't call it as string.

Comment: You have 3 options for this: `originalTextFor`, `Combine`, or `function_body.addParseAction(''.join)`. Do some experimenting with these, and see which you like the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank Mr. [PaulMcG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paulmcg), since he gave three possible answers in his comment, but I am posting a solution for somebody who might be needing it as well. `originalTextFor` did the trick for me:

```
functionName = Word(alphanums + '_')
functionBody = Forward()
functionBody <<= originalTextFor(functionName + (Literal("(") + Optional( delimitedList ( functionBody | Word(alphanums + '_') | "''"),'') + Literal(")")))
```

Now it is returning:

```
['function(param1,param2,param3)']
```